# Need to create separation between floated divs, but keep breaking them when adding margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and trying to float together three divs and then add some separation between them. when i try to add any margin, the divs break and collapse below each other.

If this involves using a clearfix, could you please explain it to me as well as help me solve it?

Here's the code...thank you :)

```css
.quick-fact-boxes {

    #quick-fact-box-one {
        height: 500px;
        background: #34495e;
        float: left;
    }

    #quick-fact-box-two {
        height: 300px;
        background: #bdc3c7;
        float: left;
    }

    #quick-fact-box-three {
        height: 200px;
        background: #95a5a6;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="quick-fact-boxes container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-one"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-two"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are using bootstrap you don't need to add float and margin in CSS, you just need to use correct classes in HTML

```
<div class="quick-fact-boxes container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-one"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-two"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 boxes" id="quick-fact-box-three"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Raheel is right. If you're using bootstrap, the numbers in your col-md class names can only add up to 12.

Comment: Ha yea my bad — you're absolutely right, BUUUUT I want the boxes to be different sizes, so my columns we're correct in the first place. When I add a margin, they still break below each other.

Comment: The goal is to have the boxes take up the amount of size i had them at. First div is col-md-5, then the next two are col-md-7 and are mean to stack on top of each other to reach the height of the first div. And then create a little separation between them all so none are touching @Raheel Khan